# tool to add to a website to allow uploading video (and ideally also recording and trimming)

Tags: video, web-development, video-editing, web-services, video-recording

Our music lessons website wants to offer a new feature where its teachers can **publish a video of themselves** on their profile.

Easy option: allow them to specify URLs of videos that they'd uploaded to YouTube.

We're curious for alternatives, though, especially because we'd prefer not requiring our users to create a 3rd party account.

Some requirements:

- the video must be uneditable

  - Our profiles have an approval process. Teachers must submit their profiles to be reviewed before they are published live on our site.  After it's approved by an admin, we want the teacher to be unable to edit the video.
- We don't want to show broken/missing videos on profiles.

  - If we go with a solution like YouTube, we also need to receive automatic notifications if a video becomes unavailable (such as a teacher deletes it or marks it private).

Ideally we could subscribe to some service that:

- allows users to upload videos
- allows users to record selfie videos from their phone and use those (instead of bothering with uploading a file)

  - ideally while recording it would show a countdown number and progress bar telling the user how many seconds remain before they hit the maximum duration (which we might define as 120 seconds).
- allows us to manage our storage costs

  - Has a mechanism for deleting videos. If a user wants to delete it (such as replacing it) or if we deem it as expired (too old and outdated) or too infrequently accessed or not worth keeping around, we should be able to delete it instead of keep paying.

Other possible features:

- If we offer a way for the user to record a video, the user should be able to review the video and re-record if it wasn't good enough.

  - and maybe even allow editing (trimming to get below the maximum duration, etc)

Thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: To what website? What is it based on? You should at least specify the programming languages used, but you're likely also using some framework(s).

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget for now.

It doesn't seem to allow recording, but it's more important for us to allow easy uploading.